# ASP.Net Razor page validation not returning values

Tags: asp.net, razor

```
    public IActionResult OnPost() {
        if (ModelState.IsValid) {
            \\ save it
        }
        return Page();
    }
```

In my razor code, I've got the above checking if the model is valid.   This works fine, if the model is valid, it saves, if not it goes to `return Page();` which is what all the documentation I can find says to do.

The problem is that if the model is invalid, the `return Page();` reloads the page so I've lost all the entered values and none of the validation messages are loaded from the model.

What should I use instead of `return Page();` to display the validation messages and keep the invalid information ?

------------------- Edit with ViewModel

So with this as my OnPost

```
[BindProperty]
public theVM.ModelinVM theVMInstance { get; set; }
public IActionResult OnPost() {
    if (ModelState.IsValid) {
        \\ save it
    }
    return theVMInstance;
}
```

and this is the view model

```
public class theVM {
    public IQueryable<originalModel> ModelinVM { get; set; }

}
```

`return theVMInstance;` 
now says
`Cannot implicitly convert type 'theVM.ModelinVM' to 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.IActionResult'.`

It's expecting an `IActionResult` so doesn't it have to be compatible with that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It didn't work because I hadn't put

```
<script src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="~/lib/jquery-validation/dist/jquery.validate.js"></script>
<script src="~/lib/jquery-validation-unobtrusive/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js"></script>
```

at the top of the .HTML page.

I didn't need the OnPost() method, the jQuery did th ejob for me.